# How to concatnate only year part in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am inserting public holidays for further reference in project, Holiday date is of DATE type and it must be of this type for some reason, i am concatenating @Year with it but it throws error
so how can i just want to put holidays with dynamic year ?

ERROR:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.


USE [AMS]
GO

Declare @Year date
Set @Year = (Select Year(Getdate()))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[GazettedHolidays]
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Kashmir Day', '05 Feb' +@Year,'Kashmir Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Pakistan Day', '23 Mar'+@Year,'Pakistan Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Labour Day', '01 May' +@Year,'Labour Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Independence Day', '14 Aug' +@Year,'Independence Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Iqbal day', '09 Nov' +@Year,'Iqbal Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Quaid-e-Azam Day', '25 Dec' +@Year,'Quaid-e-Azam Day',1       
GO
```

How ?

Comment: CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(20))

Comment: same error 

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: then you should cast(Year(Getdate()) as VARCHAR())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to case year to a varchar like this:

```
CAST(@Year as VARCHAR(4))
```

So that it gets like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GazettedHolidays]
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Kashmir Day', '05 Feb' +CAST(@Year as VARCHAR(4)),'Kashmir Day',1
...
```

And then I think that the YEAR function returns a INT not a DATE. So change this statement from this:

```
Declare @Year date
Set @Year = (Select Year(Getdate()))
```

To this:

```
Declare @Year int
Set @Year = (Select Year(Getdate()))
```

Comment: thanks sir, i edited you code a bit to remove error.
you forgot to mention 'as' in CAST

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem you need to specify the table layout.  You have a column type mismatch.

To fix the second problem, simply change the variable declarations:

```
Declare @Year varchar(255);
Set @Year = cast(year(getdate() as varchar(255));
```

I would encourage you to use ISO standard date formats (YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD) rather than relying on local date formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GazettedHolidays]
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Kashmir Day', '05 Feb' +CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)), ' Kashmir Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Pakistan Day', '23 Mar'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)), ' Pakistan Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Labour Day', '01 May' +CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) , ' Labour Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Independence Day', '14 Aug' +CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)), 'Independence Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Iqbal day', '09 Nov' +CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) , ' Iqbal Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Quaid-e-Azam Day', '25 Dec' +CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)), 'Quaid-e-Azam Day',1       
GO
```

Comment: same error

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Year VARCHAR(10)
Set @Year = (Select Year(Getdate()))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GazettedHolidays]
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Kashmir Day', '05 Feb' +@Year,'Kashmir Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Pakistan Day', '23 Mar'+@Year,'Pakistan Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Labour Day', '01 May' +@Year,'Labour Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Independence Day', '14 Aug' +@Year,'Independence Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Iqbal day', '09 Nov' +@Year,'Iqbal Day',1
Union All
Select 1, GETDATE(), 'Quaid-e-Azam Day', '25 Dec' +@Year,'Quaid-e-Azam Day',1
```